# Northern Soul(?) track very similar to intro of "Holy City" by Joan As Police Woman

Tags: identify-this-song, soul

While listening to "[Holy City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS5pjxseTQM)" by Joan As Police Woman, I keep getting an incredible feeling of deja vu/similarity from the opening chords/verse for a possibly Northern Soul song I have heard before, that is similar in pace and tone (not in a plagiaristic sense obv, just relatively similar).

Anyone have an idea what track I could be thinking of? Feel like it's constantly on the tip of my tongue but can't find it anywhere in my collection or online...

Comment: Hey @Philip - I've been listening to this artist recently based on looking her up for this question.  I've really enjoyed her work, and had never heard of her outside of this, so thx.

Comment: My pleasure @ChrisSunami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The track I was thinking of was [*Heat Wave* by Martha Reeves & The Vandellas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5k0GDQrK2jo).  The rhythm is a little different, but the notes of the repeating verse riff are very similar.